# Managed package LWC hangs page on installed orgs, but not on development environments when using lightning/refresh?

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, sandbox, installedpackage, refresh-view-api

I have a LWC in a managed package that implements a `lightning-combobox` and the `lightning/refresh` module. Those two are not directly connected, but the observed issue - page hanging - seems to be related to both.

The combobox looks like this:

```html
<lightning-combobox
  class="slds-var-m-around_xx-small"
  label="Field API Name"
  onchange={handleFieldSelected}
  options={availableFields}
>
</lightning-combobox>
```

```js
// a list of fields provided by the parent component
/** @type {string[]} */
@api availableFields = [];

fieldInfo = {
  apiName: ""
  // plus other attributes
};

handleFieldSelected(e) {
  const editorFieldSelctedApiName = e.detail.value;

  this.fieldInfo.apiName = editorFieldSelctedApiName;
}
```

Whenever the user opens the combobox and selects a field from the dropdown, the page hangs for a bit. I noticed that the longer the field list is, the more it seems to hang when an item is selected. I can see this being an issue if there were some synchronous logic when the value is selected, but there isn't, as per the snippet above.

The second issue seems to be on refreshing the view. I implemented the `lightning/refresh` module in another component:

```js
import {
  registerRefreshHandler,
  unregisterRefreshHandler
} from "lightning/refresh";

// refreshes a wired Apex property
refreshHandler() {
  refreshApex(this.wiredDefinitionInfoResult);
}

// connect the refresh handler
connectedCallback() {
  this.refreshHandlerID = registerRefreshHandler(this.template.host, this.refreshHandler);
}

// handles disconnect
disconnectedCallback() {
  unregisterRefreshHandler(this.refreshHandlerID);
}
```

Whenever I save the record that is the subject of my component, the Refresh View API is triggered and this should trigger the `refreshApex` method, as per above snippet. However the page hangs instead for minute or so and then logic continues.

The component that implements the Refresh View API is a child of the component that implements the combobox. The only event that the child publishes for the parent to handle, however, is unrelated to the logic that I detailed above.

Is anyone else facing a similar issue? I don't recall having this issue some months ago, so I'm thinking it *might* be related to the Spring '24 release too.